# How to run nodist from Cygwin

Tags: node.js, cygwin

After installing [nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist) I realized I could not use it from Cygwin. I can only use it from the windows cmd.

In the folder where it was installed I got among other files:

```
Nodist
--bin
   |--nodist
   |--npm
--node.exe
--cli.js
...
```

When trying to run it from Cygwin it fails, with error:

```
/../node.exe: No such file or directorybin/nodist: line 3: /myroute/Program Files (x86)/Nodist/bin
```

The content of  `/myroute/Program Files (x86)/Nodist/bin/nodist` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="`dirname \"$0\"`"
"$DIR/../node.exe" "$DIR/../cli" $*
```

Note: The $PATH is set in both windows and Cygwin:

```
$ which nodist
/myroute/Program Files (x86)/Nodist/bin/nodist
```

Note2: It happens the same with npm, it works under cmd but not under Cygwin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are working on it and it will probably solved in the next release:

https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist/issues/137

Answer (score 0):

Simpler approuch: 
Install the programs in a path without spaces and squares

eg, from:

```
/myroute/Program Files (x86)/Nodist/bin/nodist
```

to:

```
/myroute/Programs/Nodist/bin/nodist
```

Comment: The env variables in Cygwin come  from its own files, so the scripts to run nodist are not valid in cygwin as they are (beyond the fact of the route trick).